# SBT project not mounted to Docker container using docker-compose

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, sbt, dockerfile

When I run `docker-compose up --build` the DB container runs fine, but the app container exists with

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last Compile / bgRun' for the full output
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 30, 2020 10:07:31 AM
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command 'sbt run' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM        hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u222_1.3.5_2.13.1
MAINTAINER  <HIDDEN>
EXPOSE      8080 8000

WORKDIR     /www/app

VOLUME /www/app

RUN ["sbt", "run"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - ..:/www/app
```

My Scala project structure:

[image: Project structure]

The `Main.scala` just contains a super simple `Hello World` as you can see:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello from main scala object")
}
```

If I run the container by using `RUN ["sbt"]` in the `Dockerfile` the container stays running. I connected via `docker exec -it adcc9897d1fc bash` and could see that the `/www/app` folder is empty (besides the folders created by `sbt`). Any idea why it's empty and does not contain the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dockerfile is considered and processed, in its entirety, before most other options in the `docker-compose.yml` file are considered.  In particular an image build never sees `volumes:` from a Docker Compose setup (it also cannot see `environment:` variables or any network-related settings, including the `default` network).

That means, *at build time* (because it's a `RUN` directive), you're trying to run `sbt run` on an empty anonymous volume.  That produces the "no main class" error you're getting.

For JVM-based languages, a typical setup is to compile the application on the host, and then `COPY` the (portable) `.jar` file into your image.  The `sbt-native-packager` plugin can actually [do all of this for you](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html); if you'd prefer to do it by hand, the [`sbt-assembly` plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) can produce a "fat" `.jar` containing all of the application's dependencies.  You then get the typical minimal JVM Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY target/scala-2.13/my-app-*.jar /my-app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/my-app.jar"]
```

If you want to compile the application in the Dockerfile then you need to `COPY` the application in, and set the `CMD` to run the application when the container starts (not during the build).

```
FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt:8u222_1.3.5_2.13.1
WORKDIR /www/app

# Copy the application source in.
COPY ./ ./

# Build it.
RUN sbt compile

# Set the command to run and other metadata when the container starts.
EXPOSE 8000 8080
CMD sbt run
```

(You could also use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to combine these two Dockerfiles: first `COPY` the source tree in and `sbt compile` it, then in a second stage `COPY --from=build` only the jar file into a JRE-only image.)

Because of the `COPY` instruction, you need to set the build context to be the root of the source tree.  (It might be easier to move the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` to the repository root, next to the `build.sbt` file.)

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8000:8000"
    # No need for volumes:, source code is already in the image
```

In principle you could bind-mount your application code in as you had it in the question, and the `sbt run` command will recompile it.  You do not need a `VOLUME` directive in your Dockerfile.  You will probably find it easier to do day-to-day development on a host JDK/sbt environment.